# Express Node js sort schema objects in route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I created an application with Node js Express and I need know how to sort a schema object in the route controller. My Database is Mongo db. Here is my current working Code.

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import License from './models/license'

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tnod');

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully!');
});
app.use('/', router);

router.route('/license').get((req, res) => {
    License.find((err, licenses) => {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.json(licenses);
    });
});
```

I need something like `License.sort({"votes":1}).find() ...` Tried in different ways. Not working!

Somehow I need to sort the schema object given by `/license` route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, find() doesn't return call back function
like you did

```
License.find((err, licenses) => {})
```

In Mongoose, a sort can be done in any of the following ways:

```
License.find({}).sort('votes').exec((err, licenses) => { ... });
License.find({}).sort([['votes', 1]]).exec((err, licenses) => { ... });
License.find({}).sort({votes: 1}).exec((err, licenses) => { ... });
License.find({}, null, {sort: {votes: 1}}, (err, licenses) => { ... });
```

There’s a special syntax to work with promises in a more comfortable fashion, called “async/await”.

```
const licenses = await License.find({}).sort({'votes': 1})
```

For run that you need to make function async
In your code case

```
router.route('/license').get(async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const licenses = await License.find({}).sort({'votes': 1})
        res.json(licenses);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('error:-', e)
    }
}}
```

Most Important `License.find({ //pass condition to filter your data })`

Answer (score 0):

Following examples return all documents in the collection named **License** sorted by the **votes** field in ascending order. Specify a value to **orderby** of negative one to sort in **descending order** or a positive value (e.g. 1) to sort in **ascending** **order**.

```
 License
  .find()
  .orderby({"votes":1})
  then(response => {
   console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: This one gave me this kind of error

TypeError: _license2.default.find(...).orderby is not a function

Comment: In the top of your file, you should import License model.
And Along with that make one small change to query like => License.find({})

A pair of flower bracket was missing inside find method